# How to extract metadata from images in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, metadata, picture-library, image

SharePoint Online used to automatically extract metadata when you uploaded an image into a picture or Asset Library.  Microsoft has deprecated this feature and it is no longer available.

When uploading drone photos for building inspections, there can be thousands of photos, so it is not practical for users to input metadata values such as when the photo was taken, Longitude, Latitude, etc.

Can anyone suggest an automated solution?  I can't use SharePoint to store photos if this can't be resolved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to put some of this functionality back, “for now at least”, using a Power Automate flow

https://masteroffice365.com/exif/

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in the Date Picture Taken then using a standard picture library will be sufficient.
The Power Automate solution from Brian (https://masteroffice365.com/exif/) can be used to make image metadata available that is not exposed through the user interface.
There are also apps that provide a full set of functionalities. E.g. extract metadata from different schemes like EXIF, IPTC, XMP and ICS into columns of your choice, extract GPS coordinates into location columns and integrate with Google Maps to display the images on a map (plus preview) within SharePoint.
Paul | SLIM Applications